# How can i solve "Error using vertcat Out of memory"?

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

My code reads 7 folders of images and extract features in 7 matrices and collect all 7 matrices in one big matrix by using "vertcat", In total I have a matrix which contains features of 1745 Images and i want to classify them using Multi-SVM classifier.
This is the Error:

> Error using vertcat Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

How i can solve this problem? please.

- My OS is Windows 7 64Bit
- 4 GB RAM
- Matlab 2016a 64Bit

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MATLAB is actually running out of memory when it attempts to concatenate your matrices. There are certain memory tricks you can do to try to make this process go smoother (kill certain programs before starting matlab). Ideally you would want as little as possible running while you are trying this operation.

When you run `memory` you can see a list of items

```
 >> memory
    Maximum possible array:               4577 MB (4.800e+009 bytes) *
    Memory available for all arrays:      4577 MB (4.800e+009 bytes) *
    Memory used by MATLAB:                 330 MB (3.458e+008 bytes)
    Physical Memory (RAM):                3503 MB (3.674e+009 bytes)

    *  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

What you are probably running into is your MATLAB max possible array size isn't large enough for your array. You can try to optimize your code a bit to free up individual arrays after you concatenate them, but most likely your only options are to buy more RAM or use a smaller array.